# Visual studio 2012 project property "Always Start when Debugging"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs

When I **get** from the TFS, then all web projects have fixed property value

```
Always Start when Debugging : true
```

As shown below:

[image: project view]

Is there some way to **set and keep it to FALSE**, without the need of manually changing them one by one each time I do clean Get. (If someone forgets to do this, then all web projects in that development tree get deployed and that hangs the computer for a while...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could possibly check out [Disable Always Start When Debugging](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ccbf2ee-52a4-4783-a41c-c7057335ce28) extension, which claims to disable that option.

Comment: Unfortunate that every developer has to individually disable this.  https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/33471988-allow-disabling-alwaysstartwebserverondebug-by-def